# aggregate function by time and by group

Tags: r, time, aggregate

I am trying to construct a stacked bars using time per year and type. 
My database mat (head) looks like

```
head(mat)

  year flights.type flights.duration
1 2000         HR20         01:12:00
2 2000         HR20         02:00:00
3 2000           L4         00:54:00
4 2000           L4         00:42:00
5 2000           L4         00:22:00
6 2000         HR20         00:24:00
```

I would like to sum flights.duration by year and by type and then construct a stacked bar.

I tried to use the function aggregate but with time it does not work properly. Can anyone help me? My sum by year and by type looks like :

```
aggregate(mat$flights.duration,format(.POSIXct(mat$flights.duration,tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S"),FUN=sum, by=list(mat$year))
```

Comment: One of your problems is that you are not correctly breaking "01:12:00" and similar into correct time components. The 2 methods I use are to provide a date if all durations are less than 24 hours and use a posix function as the difference from midnight, or to pull apart this variable and perform the calculation myself. There is probably a cleaner way with a time series package.

Comment: thanks everyone for your great comment and support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `flights.duration` column to numeric minutes value as follows:

```
df$flights.duration <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                               sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x[3], ':'))) * c(60, 1, 0))
                         })
```

Then, use a grouping function such as one from `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year, flights.type) %>% summarise(flights.duration = sum(flights.duration))
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: year [?]

   year flights.type flights.duration
  <int>        <chr>            <dbl>
1  2000         HR20              216
2  2000           L4              118
```

EDIT: Adding another option that *might* be faster using `tidyr` package's `separate` instead of the above `apply` function, which loops through every row:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  separate(flights.duration, c('hours', 'mins', 'seconds'), ':') %>%
  group_by(year, flights.type) %>%
  summarise(flights.duration = sum(60 * as.numeric(hours) +
                                   as.numeric(mins) +
                                   as.numeric(seconds) / 60))
```

Result is the same as before:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: year [?]

   year flights.type flights.duration
  <int>        <chr>            <dbl>
1  2000         HR20              216
2  2000           L4              118
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `data.table` package and `as.difftime()` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mat)[, .(flights.duration.minutes = sum(as.difftime(as.character(flights.duration)))), 
              .(year, flights.type)]

   year flights.type flights.duration.minutes
1: 2000         HR20                 216 mins
2: 2000           L4                 118 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is widely considered to be the best date/time package available in R. It builds on the base R `Date` and `POSIXct` types, and adds its own `Interval`, `Duration`, and `Period` types.

The most appropriate data type for plain `hh:mm:ss` times is the `Period` type. Theoretically, it should be possible to parse your string times into `Period` values and then perform a straight grouped `sum()` with `aggregate()`.

Unfortunately, this turned out to be a much more difficult task than one would hope. I got it in the end, sort of, but it required some contortions.

---

Firstly, here's how to parse the string times into `Period` values. `lubridate` provides a convenient `hms()` method to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(2000L,2000L,2000L,2000L,2000L,2000L),flights.type=c('HR20','HR20','L4','L4','L4','HR20'),flights.duration=c('01:12:00','02:00:00','00:54:00','00:42:00','00:22:00','00:24:00'),stringsAsFactors=F);

library(lubridate);
df$flights.duration <- hms(df$flights.duration);

df;
##   year flights.type flights.duration
## 1 2000         HR20        1H 12M 0S
## 2 2000         HR20         2H 0M 0S
## 3 2000           L4           54M 0S
## 4 2000           L4           42M 0S
## 5 2000           L4           22M 0S
## 6 2000         HR20           24M 0S
```

---

Second, unfortunately, `lubridate` doesn't seem to provide a `sum()` method for the `Period` type:

```
sum(df$flights.duration);
## [1] 0
```

(In case you're wondering why it returned zero, the `Period` type is implemented by storing the seconds field as the payload of the vector, which is of double type, and the remaining fields (minutes, hours, days, months, years) are stored as slots, also of double type. All values in `df$flights.duration` have zero seconds, and the base `sum()` function only sees the vector payload, so it would sum to zero.)

I tried to fill in this gap myself using an S3 method, but soon discovered that it wouldn't work because the `Period` type is an S4 type. So I wrote this S4 method:

```
setMethod('sum',signature(x='Period',na.rm='logical'),function(x,na.rm=FALSE) period(seconds=sum(as.double(x),na.rm=na.rm),minutes=sum(x@minute,na.rm=na.rm),hours=sum(x@hour,na.rm=na.rm),days=sum(x@day,na.rm=na.rm),months=sum(x@month,na.rm=na.rm),years=sum(x@year,na.rm=na.rm)));
## [1] "sum"

sum(df$flights.duration);
## [1] "3H 154M 0S"
```

---

Unfortunately, there's still a problem: `aggregate()` tries to simplify the aggregation results by default, and this flattens the S4 result to a non-S4 object, losing the slots and corrupting the data:

```
res <- aggregate(flights.duration~year+flights.type,df,sum);
res;
## Error in paste(x@year, "y ", x@month, "m ", x@day, "d ", x@hour, "H ",  :
##   trying to get slot "year" from an object (class "Period") that is not an S4 object
traceback();
## 8: paste(x@year, "y ", x@month, "m ", x@day, "d ", x@hour, "H ",
##        x@minute, "M ", x@.Data, "S", sep = "")
## 7: format.Period(x[[i]], ..., justify = justify)
## 6: format(x[[i]], ..., justify = justify)
## 5: format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE)
## 4: as.matrix(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE))
## 3: print.data.frame(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L), flights.type = c("HR20",
##    "L4"), flights.duration = c(0, 0)))
## 2: print(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L), flights.type = c("HR20", "L4"
##    ), flights.duration = c(0, 0)))
## 1: print(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L), flights.type = c("HR20", "L4"
##    ), flights.duration = c(0, 0)))
res$flights.duration;
## [1] 0 0
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "Period"
## attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
## [1] "lubridate"
isS4(res$flights.duration);
## [1] FALSE
```

As you can see, the `aggregate()` call succeeded, but the object is corrupted. The `print.data.frame()` method fails on the column, because it happens to call `format()` on it, which dispatches to the S3 method `format.Period()`, which is a private method under the `lubridate` namespace. It fails on the corrupted object.

We can prevent simplification:

```
res <- aggregate(flights.duration~year+flights.type,df,sum,simplify=F);
res;
##   year flights.type flights.duration
## 1 2000         HR20                0
## 2 2000           L4                0
res$flights.duration;
## $`1`
## [1] "3H 36M 0S"
##
## $`4`
## [1] "118M 0S"
##
```

So technically it worked, but the column is now of list type, which is not ideal. It also doesn't display nicely anymore; we just see a zero when displayed as part of the data.frame.

---

We can fix this by transforming the column manually to combine the list components. Unfortunately, the obvious approaches of `unlist()` or `do.call(c,...)` don't work:

```
res <- transform(aggregate(flights.duration~year+flights.type,df,sum,simplify=F),flights.duration=do.call(c,flights.duration));
res;
##   year flights.type flights.duration
## 1 2000         HR20                0
## 2 2000           L4                0
res$flights.duration;
## [1] 0 0
isS4(res$flights.duration);
## [1] FALSE
```

The list of `Period` values gets flattened to a plain vector, similar to the effect of the simplification done by `aggregate()`.

The problem seems to be the list names, which prevent the `c()` call from behaving as expected. We can fix this with `unname()`. So here's the final solution:

```
res <- transform(aggregate(flights.duration~year+flights.type,df,sum,simplify=F),flights.duration=do.call(c,unname(flights.duration)));
res;
##   year flights.type flights.duration
## 1 2000         HR20        3H 36M 0S
## 2 2000           L4          118M 0S
```

---

So, although we got there eventually, I wouldn't recommend this solution. There are too many complications, gaps in functionality, and incongruous interactions between the different factions of the R ecosystem.